# MySQL query to get nested MAX() Values

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

My table look like the following.

```
-----------------------------------
|    DATE       |    SERIAL_NO    | 
-----------------------------------
| 2014-01-01    |      10001      |
| 2014-01-01    |      10002      |
| 2014-01-01    |      10003      |
| 2014-01-01    |      10004      |
| 2014-01-03    |      10001      |
| 2014-01-03    |      10002      |
| 2014-01-03    |      10003      |
| 2014-01-03    |      10004      |
| 2014-01-02    |      10001      |
| 2014-01-02    |      10002      |
| 2014-01-02    |      10003      |
| 2014-01-02    |      10004      |
-----------------------------------
```

From here I need to write the MySQL query to get the `MAX(DATE)` and for the maximum date I have to get the `MAX(SERIAL_NO)`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Please update your question with the attempts you've made or come back once you have a problem with your code.

Comment: I just used max for DATE.. I don't know how to get serial_no. so that only I have posted my question here.. So, Please help me with your answers

Comment: That's not how this site works. Post the query that you have attempted in your question.

Comment: say @Kermit this is a sample one.. I have wrote query for my application.. that is confidential. ok let me try to add something

Comment: Try to obfuscate the query.

Comment: yeah and its not that difficult to implement if u try u can do it

Answer (score 3):

```
Select date, serial_no from myTable order by date desc, serial_no desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select date, max(serial_no) from myTable where date = (select max(date) from myTable)
```